# Facebook Oauth2 cannot manually open the consent dialog Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, axios, httprequest, facebook-login

I am trying to "Manually Build a Login Flow" according to these docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/
The idea is that i want to generate an one time authorization code, then send it to my back end so it can generate there the access token and then get the user data.
The docs above nicely have sections like "Invoking the Login Dialog and Setting the Redirect URL" and "Exchanging Code for an Access Token" along with the respective endpoints to hit,  which is exactly what i want. So I started implementing the dialog invocation on the front end which is a vuejs app, so i can generate the authorization code to send it to my server.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  methods: {
    facebookAuth(){
      axios.get('https://www.facebook.com/v4.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000&state="I AM A STRING"', {
        headers:{
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        }
      })
        .then(res=>{
          console.log(res);
        })
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The first issue here is that i get CORS error, even with my anticors chrome extension open. So i pass it to this proxy `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`
and I manage to make it work, but no consent dialog opens. I just get a http response with an html page code as a response body.